# is there a way to set independent random streams in c++ using the armadillo c++ library?

Tags: c++, random, armadillo

I want two independent random streams from the armadillo rand library. it seems like they both use the same global random stream.

I can generate random numbers using the armadillo library via the following:

```
arma::arma_rng::set_seed(13)
double r = arma::randu()
```

but I am not sure how to get two random streams. In python I know I can do it by the following using the random library from numpy:

```
rn = random.RandomState(13)
rn2 = random.RandomState(11)
```

Now if I run rn.rand() and rn2.rand() they are independent and don't effect one another. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know anything about armadillo, but you can do this with the C++ standard library you know.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you require this? Do you want to be able to make one stream repeatable without modifying the other one? In any event, as @BenjaminLindley says, just use the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independent random number generators can be used in conjunction with the [.imbue()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#imbue) function in Armadillo.

The code below is adapted from [Armadillo documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html).  A C++11 compiler is required to use `std::mt19937` and `std::uniform_real_distribution`.

```
std::mt19937 engine1;  // Mersenne twister random number engine
std::mt19937 engine2;

// ... set the seeds for engine1 and engine2 here ...

std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distr(0.0, 1.0);

mat A(4,5);
mat B(4,10);

A.imbue( [&]() { return distr(engine1); } );
B.imbue( [&]() { return distr(engine2); } );
```

More info on the Mersenne engine: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine

More info on std::uniform_real_distribution: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution